# Paginated web table

Tags: javascript, jquery, cypress

I have a paginated web table which has page link buttons 'First','Previous','Next' and 'Last'. There are other page link buttons which are the number of pages the table has. However, maximum of 10 of the pages can be seen at once.  'Next' button can open other pages.  How can I write the cypress code that will loop through the pages, count the number of rows on each page and also sum up all the rows on all pages including those that are beyond the 10 visible pages?

I tried this:

it('Counts the number of rows on each page and prints the sum', () =>

```
        cy.visit('https://dockurl.vbsoft.info/') 
    
        
        let totalRowCount = 0;
    
        // Find the pagination buttons
        cy.get('.page-link')
          .each((button) => {
            
            cy.wrap(button).click();
    `your text`
            // Find the table rows on the current page
            cy.get('tbody')
              .find('tr')
              .then((rows) => {
                
                const rowCount = Cypress.$(rows).length;
    
                // Add the row count to the total
                totalRowCount += rowCount;
    
                unt}`);
              });
          })
          .then(() => {
            
            cy.log(`Total number of rows on all pages: ${totalRowCount}`);
          });

          
            const paginationElements = document.querySelectorAll('.page-link');
            const pageCount = paginationElements.length;

            console.log('Number of pages:', pageCount);

           console.log('Total Number of Request:', pageCount*rowCount)
```

``
`

It counted only the first 10 pages that can be seen.
I expect it to count all the available pages on the table

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: you could count all the rows in the page, press 'Next' button until it is disabled